# Is the average of a set of numbers minus a constant the same as each number minus the constant averaged?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is the following statement true?

$\dfrac{a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \dots + a_n}{n} - k = \dfrac{(a_1-k) + (a_2-k) + (a_3 - k) + \dots + (a_n -k)}{n} $

Comment: yes, it is true

Comment: Yes, you can write $k$ as $\frac{k+k+\dots+k}n$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\dfrac{(a_1-k) + (a_2-k) + (a_3 - k) + \dots + (a_n -k)}{n}=\dfrac{(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \dots + a_n)-nk}{n}=\dfrac{a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \dots + a_n}{n} - k$$